# Python logging, supressing output

Tags: python-3.x, logging

Here is a simple example that gets a new logger and attempts to

```
import logging

log = logging.getLogger("MyLog")
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
log.info("hello")
log.debug("world")
```

If I call `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)` right after importing, `"hello"` will print, but not `"world"`, (which seems strange since I set the level to debug).

How can the `logging` API be adjusted so all built-in levels are printed to the stdout?

Comment: You're setting the level to `INFO`, not `DEBUG`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call basicConfig with level X none of the log messages that is not covered by X will be printed.

You called `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)` Here, logging.INFO doesn't cover `logging.DEBUG`.

May be you wanted other way round?

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

This prints both info and debug output:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

log = logging.getLogger("MyLog")
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
log.info("hello")
log.debug("world")
```